# Non static method 'getUid()' cannot be reference from a static context

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a recyclerview which show an all users list in an activity. I want to get all users except currently signed in user.

I tried this :

```
 final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        // get path of database name "Users" containing users info
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        //get all data from path
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usersList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ModelUsers modelUsers = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ModelUsers.class);
                    usersList.add(modelUsers);
                    // get all users except currently signed in user
                   if (!ModelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        usersList.add(modelUsers);
                    }
                }
                adapterUser.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

But then I'm getting `Non static method 'getUid()' cannot be reference from a static context` when I added :

```
if (!ModelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                            usersList.add(modelUsers);
                        }
```

The problem is that if I make it static, I get an error in the List data.
Is there a way to solve this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you meant to use `modelUsers.getUid()` with a lowercase m, to refer to the object you just created in the lines above.

Comment: I did and the problem goes away, but when I build the project I get this error :
 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.example.schoolteacher.AllUsersActivity$1.onDataChange(AllUsersActivity.java:107)

Comment: Sounds like you have a new problem that's different than the first one.  I suggest learning how to debug your code so you can track down these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here:

```
 if (!ModelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                    usersList.add(modelUsers);
 }
```

you are calling `getUid()` method direct using class, call it using object of class. also check if Uid is null or not:

```
if (modelUsers.getUid() != null && !modelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
    usersList.add(modelUsers);
}
```

PS :

in your functioncomment `usersList.add(modelUsers);` and also check todo. update your function as:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    usersList.clear();

    //TODO CHECK HERE HOW MANY dataSnapshot OBJECTS ARE YOU GETTING

    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        ModelUsers modelUsers = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ModelUsers.class);
        //usersList.add(modelUsers);
        // get all users except currently signed in user
        if (modelUsers.getUid() != null && !modelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
            usersList.add(modelUsers);
        }
    }
      adapterUser.swapData(userList);
    //adapterUser.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Add this method in your adapter class (update variable name and data type as yours) :

```
public void swapData(ArrayList<ModelUsers> list) {
    if (list != null) {
        this.arrayList.clear();
        this.arrayList.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.schoolteacher.AllUsersActivity$1.onDataChange(AllUsersActivity.java:107)

Comment: I get the error at this line :                    if (!modelUsers.getUid().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {

Comment: check new edit in my answer, you might getting null value for Uid object

Comment: Thank you! I don't get the error anymore, but I still get the current signed in user in the recyclerview

Comment: @xLogger have you debug and check how many users are you getting in callback?/

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all of them

Comment: also check how many user have null id or has same as current one.

Comment: they all have an id, and it's different from each other

Comment: check new update, here you are notifying adapter, but not giving them new list.